# AJAX callback is fired only once

Tags: ajax

I am using `hook_form_alter()` hook to add an *Apply* button to the node edit form.. When users click on that button, an AJAX callback  replaces the text field value.

It works fine the first time, but the second time it doesn't replace the value.

```php
function course_form_node_items_edit_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['apply'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Apply'),
    '#weight' => '38',
    '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'button_test_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'edit-field-text-plain-0-value',
    ),
  );
}
    
function button_test_callback(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $item_id = $form['field_item_id']['widget'][0]['value']['#value'];
  $sql = "SELECT  item_name
          FROM items
          WHERE  field_item_id = '" . $item_id . "'";
    
  $location = \Drupal::database()->query($sql)->fetchAssoc();
    
  $form['field_text_plain']['widget'][0]['value']['#value'] = $location;
 $form['field_text_plain']['widget']['0']['value']['#id'] = 'edit-field-text-plain-0-value';
  return $form['field_text_plain'];
}
```

After the first click, the *form_text_plain* ID changes to some random value, for example *edit-field-text-plain-0-value-xhfjwos*. It seems that is the issue.

Is there any way to avoid the *form_text_plain* ID changes?

Comment: I'm guessing the wrapper ID changes when it is first replaced. It's not shown where that wrapper ID comes from though, so that's speculation.

Comment: @Jaypan now i am able to change the id of the wrapper , but it looks like the real issue is the callback is not getting the updated user form field input when the user enters the item id value second time , is there anyway to get that updated form field value to the call back ?